# adjust Gridview Width

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, visual-studio-2008, gridview

I have a Gridview that uses a collapsible panel to show a large amount of text. When the button is clicked to display the text my edit and delete button align on top of eachother as opposed to being side to side so I need to adjust the width of the Gridview in javascript. I already have the label calling a javascript function onclick but how can I adjust the width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this in JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('GridViewClientID').style.width = "500px";
```

Or, you can do it server-side by changing the GridView Width property:

```
GridView1.Width = 500;
```